# heroku App not found when checking the logs and console but not when running migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

```
$ heroku logs --app stormy-headland-566
 !    App not found.
$ heroku run console --app stormy-headland-566
Running `console` attached to terminal... failed
 !    App not found
$ heroku list
=== Dev & Legacy Apps
stormy-headland-5660
```

It's weird because I was able to run the migrations to the app and I was able to push the github repo to the app.

Comment: You're missing the 0 on the end of 556...your app's name ends with `5660`

Comment: Glad to help :0... it's always easier to have a fresh set of eyes look at something